# No problem in unit test, but problem will appear in interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

No problem in unit test, but problem will appear in interceptor

Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property us has not been initialized

```
@Component
class MyInterceptor : HandlerInterceptor {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var us:UserRepository
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
        val token = request.getHeader("token")


            val userId = JWT.decode(token).audience[0]
            val pwd = us.findByUsername(userId)
            pwd?.password.println()
            val r = pwd?.password?.let { verifyToken(it, token) }
           return true

    }
```

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : BaseRepository<MyUser> {

    fun findByUsername(username: String): MyUser?
}
```

```
@NoRepositoryBean
interface BaseRepository<T> : JpaRepository<T, String>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>,
    CrudRepository<T, String> {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily avoid *lateinit property xxx has not been initialized* by using constructor injection.

Like:

```kotlin
@Component
class MyInterceptor(private val userRepository:UserRepository) : HandlerInterceptor {
   
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
       ...
       userRepository.findByUsername(userId)
       ...

    }
```

On the other hand, your code should work. I think there is something wrong with your package-structure (component-scan). Ref: [structuring-your-code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class)

Working simplified demo [here](https://gist.github.com/700a3e728707e6e5f356fc39d0c8b629)